# breadcrumbs navigation in Go application

Tags: go, navigation, breadcrumbs, go-templates

I'm very new to Golang and I'm trying right now to dynamically generate breadcrumbs navigation in my go app.
Right now I have been able to make it in a static way in a go template:

```
{{ define "breadcrumbs" }}

<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
  <ul class="breadcrumb">
      <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Products</li>
  </ul>
</nav>

{{ end }}
```

But I want my application to generate this on every page. Unfortunately I haven't found any useful examples online.

Comment: Are you asking how to implement hierarchical breadcrumbs where the hierarchy is fixed for a given page?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean with a "fixed" hierarchy! I want to add a widget at the top of every page with the navigation e.g. `Home / Products / Product 1`. And to be able to click on each link to go back to that specific end point.

Comment: In that case it should be fixed, as you described it. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Define `type Breadcrumb { Name string;  HREF string }`.  Pass []Breadcrumb to the template through the data argument.  Range over the breadcrumbs in the template.

Comment: And after that, is there a way to make the name and the href for every page?

Comment: Construct the slice of breadcrumbs in the handler for each type of page.  For example, on a product page use `[]Breadcrumb{ {"Home", "/"}, {"Products", "/products"}, {productName, productURL}}`